# Static Next.js Page for Github is giving a strange error when building it

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I finished coding my new portfolio using Next.js, but I have a problem that I really don't know how to fix.

Everytime I try to use "next build" to create a github pages website, I receive a bunch of errors regarding the usage of useEffect().
It runs normally with "npm run dev", but when I try to build it, it fails.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: 'export',
}
```

I'm using the correct output mode to export as far as I know.

What I already tried:

1. Checking if I'm import React properly " **import { useState } from 'react'**"
2. Creating a new project and re-writting it all from scratch to find any typos or bad usages of useEffect().
3. Deleting every single import and usages of useEffect(), now, the problem is useStat, if I comment that, goes to the next one, such as useRef.

Ps: This is the error (quite large, only two of many of the same type (same text))

```
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
>     at exports.useEffect (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Profile\portfolio\next\usern-port\node_modules\react\cjs\react.production.min.js:24:292)
>     at Layout (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Profile\portfolio\next\usern-port\.next\server\chunks\643.js:266:34)
>     at Wc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at $c (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
> 
> Error occurred prerendering page "/projects/the-naughty-bottle". Read
> more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
>     at exports.useEffect (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Profile\portfolio\next\usern-port\node_modules\react\cjs\react.production.min.js:24:292)
>     at Layout (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Profile\portfolio\next\usern-port\.next\server\chunks\643.js:266:34)
>     at Wc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at $c (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
>     at exports.useEffect (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Profile\portfolio\next\usern-port\node_modules\react\cjs\react.production.min.js:24:292)
>     at Layout (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Profile\portfolio\next\usern-port\.next\server\chunks\643.js:266:34)
>     at Wc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at Zc (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
>     at Z (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
>     at $c (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
```

Comment: @lorengphd Yes, I was actually being dumb. I forgot to first build it, then publish it. 
You can do this by: 
>npm run build
>npx next export

Idk how to close this question, but if a MOD see this, please do.